# React dynamic image importing in development

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, create-react-app

I am building a React application which needs to display images dynamically which are stored, by the thousands, on a server-side file system. All of my attempts to successfully implement this have failed, including many which were taken from responses to similar questions.

Some details:
I used create-react-app to initialize my application. I am running in development mode (have not run npm-build). I'm using Express.js (Node.js) as a web-server, which I interact with through a proxy (only '/api' http requests use the proxy). My js code which attempts to 'require' the images is in the 'src' folder. The images are located in an 'images' folder in the default 'public' folder.

I thought I had found the solution when reading [this page from create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder), as it states to use the public folder when 'You have thousands of images and need to dynamically reference their paths'. The page further instructs to use '%PUBLIC_URL%' or 'process.env.PUBLIC_URL' to access the 'public' folder. When using either of these I receive an 'Error: Cannot find module' message. Upon checking I notice that 'process.env.PUBLIC_URL' contains an empty string, and quickly notice that PUBLIC_URL [is ignored in development mode](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/advanced-configuration).

I find this to be tremendously confusing, given that the '[Using the Public Folder](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder)' page is apparently describing the development phase of production, and yet it advises the use of something which is meaningless during development. Adding to my confusion, it appears as if the contents of that page resolved the issue for nearly all of those who have encountered a similar requirement in the past ([example: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196800/reactjs-and-images-in-public-folder/48730272), [example: 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50729967/src-images-folder-in-create-react-app); both fail for me). Likewise, all attempts to to construct relative paths to the 'public' folder from the 'src' folder have yielded error messages. Failed code example:

```
let img = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/images/Team.jpg';
<img src={require(`${img}`)} alt="X" />

Error: Cannot find module '/images/Team.jpg'
```

I never imagined showing images in React would be so difficult. Any help is truly very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are correct, you just don't need the `require`, `return <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/logo.png'} />;` as you can see their [docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder)

If you open in your browser `http://localhost:PORT/images/Team.jpg` that should open. 
That's the reason `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` is empty in development, because they resolve everything inside this folder directly.

Comment: You are a hero sir thank you, just needed to omit require, I don't know how I missed that. Wasted two days of my life on this if you can believe it...